# Como posso esconder ou mostrar um div de uma página para a outra?

Tags: php, javascript, html, div, alert

Tenho um ficheiro em que as pessoas escrevem nos campos:

```
<div class="banner-bot" >
<div class="container">
    <h2>Registar</h2>
    <p>Preenche os dados para criar a tua conta. Quando te registares irá ser enviado um email para confirmares a conta. </p>
    <br>
</div>
<form name="registarUtilizador" action="Inserir/InserirUtilizador.php" onsubmit="return validarRegisto()" method="POST">
    <div class="register-box">
        <div class="text">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo" required=""  name="nomeCompleto" id="nomeCompleto"  maxlength="99"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required="" name="email" id="email" maxlength="99"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Confirme o seu Email" required="" name="emailConfirmar" id="emailConfirmar" maxlength="99"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" name="pass" id="" maxlength="20"/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirme a sua Password" required="" name="passConfirmar" id="passConfirmar" maxlength="20"/>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="text-but">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirmar"/>
        </div>  
    </div>
</form>
```

E quando o botão submit é clicado, irá ser verificado o formato do email, se o email já existe na base de dados... tudo em um outro ficheiro. E o que eu queria era criar um div ou um alert, ou seja, uma forma de informar que o email já está registado e retornar para a página de registo. E o mesmo quando o registo é efetuado com sucesso. Retornar para a página principal avisando o utilizador que a sua conta foi registada com sucesso.

Código de verificação:

```
<?php require '../functions.php'; ?>
<body>
<?php

$nomeCompleto = $_POST["nomeCompleto"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
];
$pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

// Create connection
$conn = db_connect(); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO utilizadores (nomeCompleto, email, pass) 
VALUES ('$nomeCompleto', '$email', '$pass')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    // Retornar para a página index e avisar o utilizador que foi registado com sucesso
    header("Location: ../index.php");
} else {
    //Retorar para a página registar e avisar o utilizador que o email já está inserido/registado
    header("Location: ../registar.php");

}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Creio que existem duas formas de fazer isso. A primeira é com Ajax, a segunda é na pagina registar você ter um get preparado e fazer algo +- assim: `Location: ../registar.php?value=fail`

Answer (score 1):

você pode tratar essas mensagens por "GET" vou mostrar:

nessa parte do seu codigo coloca algo como:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    // Retornar para a página index e avisar o utilizador que foi registado com sucesso
    header("Location: ../index.php?msg=sucesso");
} else {
    //Retorar para a página registar e avisar o utilizador que o email já está inserido/registado
    header("Location: ../registar.php?msg=erro");

}
```

Agora na sua pagina registro e index você coloca algo como:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET["msg"]) && $_GET["msg"] == "sucesso") {
    //Aqui você coloca código html com formatação de msg
 }
?>
```

Basicamente, se tiver get ele ira mostrar o conteúdo do if

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou na perfeição. 

Queria também perguntar se é possível fazer com que não seja possível os utilizadores não acedam a essa página (registar.php?msg=erro) sem ser por erro de registo.

Comment: Nesse caso só consigo pensar em uma alternativa, uma requisição ajax, assim você pode retornar uma parte de um código html inteiro para seu "registar.php", da uma lida sobre requisição ajax, qualquer coisa posso te dar uma ajuda.